# Why is this not returning the lowest total score value in my SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm new to SQL queries and need some help with my methods to fetch the lowest score, currently it's fetching a value but it's not the lowest one in my database. Image attached

[image: SQLite Databse]

And Below is the label that is meant to be showing this information,

[image: Output]

This is my methods to get this result and the DBHandler class

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String Name = "GolfScores";
    private static final int ver = 1;
    public static final String tableName = "guestScores";
    public static final String DBId = "id";
    public static final String DBName = "name";
    private static final String DBHole1 = "hole1";
    private static final String DBHole2 = "hole2";
    private static final String DBHole3 = "hole3";
    public static final String DBTotal = "totalScore";
    public static final String DBDate = "DatePlayed";

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, Name, null, ver);
    }

    // below method is for creating a database by running a sqlite query
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // on below line we are creating
        // an sqlite query and we are
        // setting our column names
        // along with their data types.
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " ("
                + DBId + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + DBName + " TEXT,"
                + DBHole1 + " TEXT,"
                + DBHole2 + " TEXT,"
                + DBHole3 + " TEXT,"
                + DBTotal + " TEXT,"
                + DBDate + " TEXT)" +
                " ";

        // at last we are calling a exec sql
        // method to execute above sql query
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public void addNewPlayer(String playerName, String Hole1Score, String Hole2Score, String Hole3Score, String CourseScore, String DatePlayed) {
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(DBName, playerName);
            values.put(DBHole1, Hole1Score);
            values.put(DBHole2, Hole2Score);
            values.put(DBHole3, Hole3Score);
            values.put(DBTotal, CourseScore);
            values.put(DBDate, DatePlayed);

            db.insert(tableName, null, values);
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DBHandler", "Error adding player: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // this method is called to check if the table exists already.
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    String TAG = "DBHandler";
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public String getTableAsString(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getTableAsString called");
        String tableString = String.format("Table %s:\n", tableName);
        Cursor allRows  = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, null);
        if (allRows.moveToFirst() ){
            String[] columnNames = allRows.getColumnNames();
            do {
                for (String name: columnNames) {
                    tableString += String.format("%s: %s\n", name,
                            allRows.getString(allRows.getColumnIndex(name)));
                }
                tableString += "\n";

            } while (allRows.moveToNext());
        }

        return tableString;
    }


}
```

This is the method I've got for getting the lowest score

```
 private void getLowest() {
        TextView lowestScoreTextView = findViewById(R.id.lowestScoringPlayerTXT);

        // Assuming you have a DBHandler class with the table name and column names
        DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(Menu.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();

        // Execute the query to retrieve the lowest scoring player
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + DBHandler.DBName + "," + DBHandler.DBTotal + " FROM " + DBHandler.tableName + " ORDER BY " + DBHandler.DBTotal + " ASC LIMIT 1", null);

        // Check if there is a result
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // Retrieve the data from the cursor
            String playerName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.DBName));
            int totalScore = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.DBTotal));

            // Create a string representation of the result
            String resultString = "Player Name: " + playerName + "\nTotal Score: " + totalScore;

            // Set the text of the TextView
            lowestScoreTextView.setText(resultString);
            Log.d("Debug", "Player Name: " + playerName + ", Total Score: " + totalScore);
        } else {
            // Handle the case where there is no result
            lowestScoreTextView.setText("No data found");
        }

        // Close the cursor and the database
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
```

In the data provided I want the label to show just one of the players with the lowest score if they are tying in lowest score, and it should update whenever the method is ran. Currently I have it running the method twice once on the start new button click and another on a RunOnUiThread.

In this case I wish for the label to say either player 1 score 7 or player 2 score 7 as they are both the same total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created your Table using "TEXT" for fields/columns where you're inserting NUMBERS, so the ORDER BY will not convert TEXT to INTEGER to order in the way you're expecting.
You have these solutions:

1. don't use TEXT but use DECIMAL instead for table's "*totalScore*" column
2. do a cast like this: " ORDER BY CAST(" + DBHandler.DBTotal + " AS DECIMAL) ASC LIMIT 1" (the Cast command could be different based on what your SQL engine)

Without using a NUMBER/INTEGER columns, the ORDER BY is done by ASCII values and not numerical value.